# AWK if loop - If any value is less than one

Tags: awk, gawk

I produce a huge multi-column output file running some analytical software on angle populations. Sadly, the angles are defines as -180° to 180° and I need 0°-360°.

What I want do to is take this entire input file and replace every negative value with the sum of "360+value" while maintaining every positive value unchanged and printing everything in a tab delimited output file, just like the original input file.

I manage to do this simple enough for 1 column at a time:

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t" }; { if($2 < 0) print $1, 360+$2; else print $1, $2}' INPUT > OUTPUT
```

And I guess that I could do this for every column by including more "ifs" like so:

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t" }; { if($2 < 0 || $3 < 0) print $1, 360+$2, 360+$3; else print $1, $2, $3}' INPUT > OUTPUT
```

Or something similar, however there must be a better way to do this. I tried playing around with "`$0`" instead though I could not get this to work either.

So is there a nice one-liner (or input script) to check every value in every column if it is less than 0 (a negative number) and print all positive values as is while "adding" 360 to every negative value along the lines of:

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t" }; { if($0 < 0) print 360+$0; else print $0}' INPUT > OUTPUT
```

I do understand that this command wont work though basically this is what I want, maintain the same format as input, if a value is negative then add 360 and print, otherwise just print.

Thank you in advance, all input is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple `for` loop e.g.

```
{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i < 0) $i+=360}; print}
```

Comment: I'll try this as soon as todays meeting is finished... Though it looks like what I was looking for.

Comment: So, I'm just losing the first text filed on the file so #Frame gets replaced with 360 however I assume I could get around this problem with a "skip" (NF>1) or something. Otherwise this solution was just what I had in mind. Thank you

Comment: @gusgrave if there is a first non-numeric field, you can start the loop from `i=2`